# Accessing Private methods in subclass using super class reference

Tags: java

```
package privatePkg;
class privateImp {
    private void print() {
        System.out.println("Inside the PrivateImp class method "+this);
    }

    public void access() {
        print();
    }
}

class SubClass extends privateImp {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        System.out.println("In the subclass");
        SubClass sb = new SubClass();
        sb.access();
    }
}
```

Here as the `print()` method is declared private in the super class `privateImp`, and we extend that class. When I create a subclass object and try to access the inherited method `access()` it is also invoking the private method of the super class. As it is a private method it should not be accessed in other classes but only the members of that class can access it. Then how did the private method get invoked by the `access()` on subclass object?

Can please tell me as I did not override the `access()` method inherited from superclass will the compiler replace the line inside `accesss()` in the subclass as follows:

```
class SubClass extends privateImp() {
    public void access() {
        super.access();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly; you access a publicly facing method `access()` which in turn internally called the private method `print()`.  This is how encapsulation is supposed to work, and there is nothing wrong/unexpected about your current approach.

Comment: To expand @Tim's comment, if you tried to put your `access` on `SubClass`, it wouldn't work (presuming they're in different files). Your `main` isn't accessing `print`, the (publicly visible) `PrivateImp.access` is.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass does not inherit the private members of its parent class. However, if the superclass has public or protected methods for accessing its private fields, these can also be used by the subclass.

A nested class has access to all the private members of its enclosing class—both fields and methods. Therefore, a public or protected nested class inherited by a subclass has indirect access to all of the private members of the superclass.

Read official docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you cannot directly access a private method from outside the class, that is you cannot invoke the private method by its name.

So, in order to access a private method from outside the class, you need to call one of its public proxies, i.e. one of the public methods of the class which have access to the private method and act as an interface to it, which is what you're doing.

This is the fundamental principle of Data Abstraction/Data Hiding in action.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to override the `access()` function and doesn't want the `print()` function being accessed by other classes but only the members of that class can access it.

you can simply change the modifier of `print()` function from `private` to `protected`. Also you can delete `access()` function as you no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

Access control in Java is not based on which class is calling the method at run time. It's based on where the calling code is in the source code.

Here, the call to the private method is in the `privateImp` class, so it's allowed. It does not matter that you have created a subclass, and called `access` on an instance of the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

SubClass main method is calling the access() in privateImp class and from there print() is called. You can see this if you open the call hierarchy of print(). Whenever you override access() and again open call hierarchy you can see the difference. This is the default behavior if you extend a class and don't override visible methods.

By the way class names should not start with small case.

Answer (score 0):

The subclass is calling a public method, but how the called method works, ie., what private fields or methods it accesses, is not the calling method's business. The subclass itself is not directly calling the private method, so there is no problem.
This is also how getters and setters work...

```
private String name;
public void setName(String name){
  //do something
  this.name=name;
}
public String getName(){
  //do something
  return name;
}
```

If methods from other classes could not call the getters and setters, they would have no reason to exist.
In fact, if you think about it, **if public methods could not be called because somewhere in the chain of execution a private field or method is accessed, then private fields or methods would not be used anywhere other than the main class.**